# What's the advantage of declaring a function as a var?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

I've seen this in a lot of scripts. When is it better to do

```
var foo = function() { console.log("Foo!"); };
```

than

```
function foo() { console.log("Foo!"); }
```

when it's obvious that `function name(){}` is more compact and seems to do the same things? At first, I thought it was so you could use `foo` as a variable, but you can still do that with both methods. They can even both be redeclared by either method.

**I know that `var foo = function(){};` creates the function at runtime**, but I don't see the advantage of this, because it can lead to crashes, which I assume are unwanted.

Comment: @thefourtheye right, like I said, I know the *difference*, I just don't know the *point*

Comment: Lets say, based on a condition, you want to create two different functions dynamically. Will that be possible with `function ...()` method?

Comment: I see... `if (bar) function foo(){console.log("bar");} else function foo(){console.log("foo");};` creates when parsing, so despite the value of `bar`, `foo` is always the last-declared version

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function as :

```
function foo() { console.log("Foo!"); }
```

In simple words, JS engine loads this function before executing the code. However, if you declare a function with var, it is only processed when the js engine starts executing.

```
foo(); // Fine
foo1(); //Error

function foo() { console.log("Foo!"); }

var foo1 = function(){};
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this?

Comment: @Supuhstar Some functions may be not necessary in specific situations, but implemented for other situations.